# Not enough reputation to answer a closed question, but I believe I have a viable answer

Tags: support

A question about interpersonal interactions was closed due to low-quality answers. I do not have the required 10 reputation to answer.

The moderator did not state why the answers were low-quality. So I read all of the answers and the problem I detected is that the answers were based on non-verified assumptions.

If true, then I have an answer that works.

As a goodwill gesture, is there a way to email my answer to the person who asked the question? Their profile does not have any contact information.

Comment: You might have some misunderstanding about closed questions. No one can answer a closed question until it's re-opened. It has nothing to do with reputation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the question?

Comment: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/47646/how-to-deal-with-people-judging-your-overproductiveness/47775#47775

Comment: You seem to be confusing 'closed' with '[protected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question)' questions - it would be good for the long-term usefulness of this thread if you edited the question title to reflect this. If that is the case, consider the possibility that there are deleted answers which are low quality and which you cannot see.

Answer (score 5):

I am going to guess here. There is a different between closed/on hold and protected questions. Questions do not get closed because of "low quality answers",but we do protect them. The reason you do not see the low quality answers, is that they get deleted by high rep users and moderators.

The best way to be able to post an answer on a protected question, is to earn the required reputation by asking/answering other questions on the site.

Comment: You are right, I misunderstood. I reviewed the question and thread again, and it is protected and not closed.